# Use HTML5 Canvas to "plot" 2d array from local csv

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to do an exercise in data visualization using the browser to plot the contents of a local text file.
Both the html and the txt are local, and it is for prototyping/personal-use only.

Basically, I would want to use, say, javascript, to read a file just like this:

```
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
0.0, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.0
0.0, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.5, 0.3, 0.0
0.0, 0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 0.6, 0.3, 0.0
0.0, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.5, 0.3, 0.0
0.0, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.0
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
```

and render as a square grid of colored circles. Each value from the txt would be the opacity of the correspondent circle, like this (made using Python, Numpy, Cairo and PIL):

[image]

I am a complete beginner on javascript and HTML5 Canvas, so I would appreciate very much a clue so as to what I should do, which functions to use, etc.

There's no need to give complete code (but it would be nice!), just the name of the functions and concepts, so that I can look for tutorials and assemble my Frankenstein from a bunch of "Hello Worlds", or anything like that.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR : http://bv.iriscouch.com/so/_design/ex/index.html and http://bv.iriscouch.com/so/_design/ex/separate-function.html

This is a slightly verbose answer but I feel like I was in your shoes not too long ago, and would have benefitted from some of the below pointers. I will target it with Python analogies since you mentioned those Python libraries. Also feel like mentioning: I like low-level stuff, I love oscilloscopes, C, etc., but the beautiful, lower-level heart of javascript is its objects and functions -- the browser environment is a jungle and I am much happier since handing off as much as possible to jQuery and Underscore.js.

First, regarding csv format, if it's an absolute requirement use something like d3.csv from the [d3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/) library. (In fact, regard all data vizualization javascript you learn from now forward as preparation for copying as much as possible from the imagination of [Mike Bostock](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/).) But asking about csv in Javascript is a bit like asking "I'm new to Asia, where is the best place to get sushi in Sichuan?" Answer: "You're [in Sichuan!!!](https://www.google.com/search?q=sichuan%20cuisine&hl=en&safe=off&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=JPDfTq2yOcTWiAL9u4niDg&ved=0CGkQsAQ&biw=1271&bih=679)". Use `json`. In python in your case I would just do:

```
>>> f = open('sample.csv').readlines()
>>> rv = json.dumps([[float(i) for i in k.split(',')] for k in f])
>>> file_out.write(rv)
```

Here is how you do it in one piece: http://bv.iriscouch.com/so/_design/ex/index.html

Here is how you might break it up into the core function that then gets rendered on the page's canvas: http://bv.iriscouch.com/so/_design/ex/separate-function.html

(Parenthetically, try [iriscouch.com](http://iriscouch.com), it is one of the coolest things on the internet, and a good way to get familiar with Javascript. The below examples are there. `sudo pip install couchapp`, `couchapp generate ex`, `cp *.js *.html ex/_attachments`, `cd ex && couchapp push https://user:pass@youraccount.iriscouch.com/somename` is how I put up these examples, totally free. Windows installer [here](http://couchapp.org/page/installing).)

If you want to look at the underlying data as reformatted, that's [here](http://bv.iriscouch.com/_utils/document.html?so/_design/ex).

Finally, you can see more of my personal babysteps in this stuff at http://aguacat.es

Inline of above example:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="circles" height="700" width="700"></canvas>
    <script>
      // $ is just a function. It makes dealing with the
      // browser itself less annoying. Call it with a
      // function as argument. The function has no
      // name, like a python lambda, and it will
      // request the json and process it.
      $(function () {
        var the_color = "rgba(0,0,255,alpha_token)";
        // ask for the json and register the following
        // function (second argument to getJSON) to be called 
        // once it is delivered:
        $.getJSON('json_from_csv.json', function(data) {
          // no more jquery for now
          var canvas = document.getElementById("circles");
          // you declare these to avoid them being global variables:
          var h, w, column_width, column_height, x_pos, y_pos, radius;
          h = canvas.height;
          w = canvas.width;
          column_width = w / data[0].length;
          column_height = h / data.length;
          // we're working in 2 dimensions:
          var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
          radius = column_width / 2; 
          data.forEach(function (row, row_index) {
            row.forEach(function (entry, column_index) {
              x_pos = column_index * column_width + radius;
              y_pos = row_index * column_height + radius;
              context.moveTo(x_pos, y_pos);
              context.beginPath();
              context.arc(x_pos, y_pos, radius, 0, Math.PI*2)
              context.fillStyle = the_color.replace(/alpha_token/, entry);
              context.strokeStyle = the_color.replace(/alpha_token/, entry);
              context.fill();
              context.stroke();
              context.closePath();
            });
          });
          });
        });
      </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh, my, THIS was a detailed answer. Thank you so much for caring! I am pretty in-a-hurry today, but I will study your examples carefully asap. Thanks again!

Comment: sorry to bother again, but I cannot access content from a local file using javascript (I guess it has to do with security), so I am wondering how I could drag and drop a file into a "drag and drop" zone, so that the file (a .json one) would be rendered in a canvas. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Just for the record: Everything worked with SimpleHTTPServer (I am going to test apache too), but "no one told me" I should use `jquery.js`. By the way, I copied it to the directory. +1 for the SimpleHTTPServer tip!

Answer (score 2):

Responding to Heltonbiker. It's very possible to store acces data locally with javascript, for example you could create a json object store it in a var and save the file locally. Your file would look something like:

```
var jsonObject = {

    "priorities": [ [1,12], [4,2] ]
}
```

Now if you include your local file in the head of your script as such:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="priorities.json"></script>
```

Now I can acces data from my index.html stored in the same directory to manipulate my canvas.

Jeffrey thank you for the helpfull articles I'm looking for a way to draw a [plot](http://www.atnf.csiro.au/people/pulsar/psrcat/proc_form.php?version=1.51&JName=JName&P0=P0&P1=P1&startUserDefined=true&c1_val=&c2_val=&c3_val=&c4_val=&sort_attr=jname&sort_order=asc&condition=&pulsar_names=&ephemeris=short&coords_unit=raj%2Fdecj&radius=&coords_1=&coords_2=&style=Long%20with%20last%20digit%20error&no_value=*&fsize=3&x_axis=p0&x_scale=linear&y_axis=p1&y_scale=linear&state=query&plot_bottom.x=55&plot_bottom.y=34) from two datasets in pure javascript no libraries and this was some nice info on that :)

Comment: Yeah, I started do to this some time ago. But actually it would be sort of "wrong" name the file `priorities.json`. Is should be named `priorities.js`, or at least `priorities.jsonp`, since the file content is valid javascript, but not valid json.

Comment: You are completely right it doesn't pass the validator :)

Answer (score 1):

It's very possible!

You can read local text files through JavaScript via the xmlhttprequest object, and parse its contents with regular expressions or a similar method.

Unfortunately, I'm not very good with string parsing, but I whipped up this example for loading a file and drawing circles on a canvas.

script.js:

```
var Visualizer =  {

    canvas      : document.getElementById("canvas"),
    context     : this.canvas.getContext("2d"),
    fileContents    : "",

    //Load a local file
    loadFile    : function(address) {
        var file = (window.XMLHttpRequest)?new XMLHttpRequest():new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        if(file == null) {
            console.log("Error: XMLHttpRequest failed to initiate.");
        }
        file.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (file.readyState == 4) { //Completed loading
                if (file.status == 200 || file.status == 0) {

                    //The responseText is the contents of the text file
                    fileContents = file.responseText;

                    Visualizer.onFileLoad();
                }
                else    //Otherwise, there was a problem while loading
                    console.log("Error " + file.status + " has occurred.");
            }
        }
        try {
            file.open("GET", address, true);
            file.send(null);

        } catch(e) {
            console.log("Error retrieving data file. Some browsers only accept cross-domain request with HTTP.");
        }

    },

    //Called when the xmlhttprequest object loads the file successfully
    onFileLoad  : function() {
        this.parseFile();
    },

    //Iterates through a file and draws circles
    parseFile   : function() {

        var x = 0;
        var y = 0;


        //~~~Create some method for parsing the text~~~

        var r = 100;
        var g = 100;
        var b = 255;

        var color = "rgba("+r+","+g+","+b+",1)";

        this.drawCircleAt(x+25, y+25, color);



    },


    //Draws circles with a 25 pixel diameter at the position specified.
    drawCircleAt    : function(x, y, color) {

        this.context.fillStyle = color;
        this.context.beginPath();
        this.context.arc(x, y, 25, 0, 6.283, false);
        this.context.fill();
        this.context.closePath();

    }


}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500">
        </canvas>
        <script type="text/Javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        <script>
            Visualizer.loadFile("file.txt");
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you have any questions about the code, ask away.

Comment: for some reason, the canvas is being drawn, but is empty. I created the files in a directory. Is your example intended to work as is or is it just a draft upon which I could actually get my desired result?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. You need a text file called "file.txt" in the same directory as the index.html and script.js file. While the canvas doesn't actually parse anything, it should draw one circle on the screen.